Should We Make Reputation Score Invisible?
I am seeing the same pattern over and over:
The higher reputation the user has, the higher score his/her answer gets.
As if someone thinks “ah, this person has high rep, therefore, the answer must be excellent!”
Some medium rep users make answers not for the sake of good solution, but instead posting mediocre solutions just chasing the score points.
I am sure we would get better answers and the answers would get proper scores if the reputation become invisible, only giving more authority/access.
UPD. With this question, my only goal is better answers, no accusation whatsoever.

That sounds a bit inflammatory. I haven't noticed a pattern of high reputation users just chasing points. It seems to me that some of the highest reputation users actually hold back or delay their answers. But setting that aside, what would be the point of having reputation scores if no one could see the scores?

@lericr what exactly do you mean by “inflammatory” ?

I think "users make answers not for the sake of good solution, but instead posting lousy solutions just chasing the score points" sounds inflammatory. Both the "lousy" and the "chasing score points"

@lericr well don’t know why this irritates you personally . Haven’t noticed you making so-so answers to get the points )) But, setting that aside, the point of invisible reputation would be similar to wealth: your bank account is invisible to me and it’s the right thing. So, having more “invisible rep” would bring the user more authority and access level etc.

And I didn't take your comment as being directed at me specifically. It just sounds generally like an accusatory statement. But I'll just assume positive intent and set that aside.

Yeah that’s the way

I'm not even sure we can do that. The whole reputation thing is kind of inherent to SE. People trying to learn something new have some way of distinguishing good answers from bad. The assumption is that answers from high rep user will on average be better answers. Yes, it's an assumption that won't always be correct, but that's the foundation of SE, at least as far as I understand SE.

Per your update, if the goal is better answers, what's your hypothesis for why hiding reputation scores would lead to better answers? Also, what purpose would reputation scores serve at all? Why wouldn't we just eliminate them altogether if it actually worked to produce better answers?

And why should we assume that people with medium reputation are gaming the system with mediocre answers instead of just assuming that mediocre answers are actually representative of the knowledge of medium reputation users? I mean, the reputation thing could be working as intended.

Side note, but maybe not unrelated... how are scores actually distributed? I've been assuming that my reputation score is squarely in the medium category.

Strange.. you’re asking for the same clarification, twice. Please refer to my earlier answer!

Do you feel like your personal reputation score 1) is of high value to you personally or 2) is very desirable as a tool to get more public attention/respect or 3) do you view it as a mere tool to get access / authority inside the SE system (aka power) ?

Okay, I see that I've misled you somehow, so I'll start fresh. I don't care about my reputation at all. I find other people's reputations useful, however. If I notice someone with a very high reputation, I might actually look at some of their other answers. I might be more likely to remember their alias and take special note of new answers from them. I might ask them specific questions in chat rooms. I admit to getting a small dopamine hit when I notice an upvote on an answer of mine, but my overall reputation score is of no value to me.

I can totally see the appeal of a forum that is just like Mathematica SE but without the reputation score. But coming to SE and suggesting that the SE community ditch reputation scores is like going to church and asking them to ditch praying. I find praying to be creepy, but I still think it would be presumptuous to go to church and ask them to stop.

In other words, I don't think you wanting a forum without reputation scores is in any way unreasonable. I'm just telling you that, as far as I can tell, what you're asking is for StackExchange to not be StackExchange.

Well I could care less about others feelings really.

You got a point with the Church of the Upvote. :) and me coming with the Pray the Lords of the Good Answers.

Well, I'm not really asking you to care about other's feelings. I'm just saying you've chosen to question the one thing that is almost certainly not going to change. And I have no problem with you questioning that. If I were to design my ideal q&a forum from scratch, it'd be very different than StackExchange. But I didn't put any of my own effort into building my own q&a site and I don't contribute anything to the framework itself, so I don't really have much leg to stand on in terms of criticism.

(1) Should there be anonymous answers (and questions)? (2) Why do people with high reputation get upvoted even for worthless answers? (3) The problem with reputation: does high reputation attract too many upvotes?

(4) Rich get richer phenomenon on CV (5) The Stack Exchange reputation system: What's working? What's not? and so on ...

@Domen so this is inherently unsolvable I see..

@Anton I think the links provided by Domen are instructive. I can state categorically that reputation is not the “fun” part of the site for me. I am guilty of providing quick superficial answers but the “fun” comes from better answers and the value comes from mutually respectful communication of errors. What has detracted from positive aspects of site is a very small number of users who have a recurring pattern of pejorative and abusive comments. This continues to this day and is not instructive or edifying.

@ubpdqn are you implying some sort of passive aggression ?

@Anton Not passive

@ubpdqn believe it or not, active means honest, in this very case.

@Anton I am not sure I understand what you mean. I have no problem with honest communication. This is usually constructive if based on mutual openness. Honesty is not what I am referring to and there are many other users who have experienced the same adverse effects from a small pool of frankly abusive users.

@Anton I think your question was not aggressive and just to be clear you are not one of users I am referring to.  I am recovering from major surgery and perhaps a little too sensitive.

@ubpdqn I remember)! Get well. I am all for clearness too. So, I am (active) aggressive sometimes, but not in this question. However, I only become aggressive in response to passive aggression. I see a lot of passive aggressive abusers here. And I’m not referring to you, too.
